# Implementing eForm using editable pdf in MVC.net Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, razor

I am trying to implement eForm which enable users to  fill online and after submitting the form, filled data will be stored in database. eForm needs to in editable PDF mode.

I tried ActivePDF Portal application to implement editable PDF, but its DLL's supports only for ASP.net and not for MVC4 razor.

So My question is, how can I implement editable PDF as eForm in MVC4?